# Column width in Excel to PDF

Tags: c#, excel, pdf, pdf-generation, excel-2019

I am trying to convert a Excel document to PDF. The Excel document has 64 pixels width for first 10 columns.  I am using the A4 Sheet size for PDF in which the first 10 columns should fit. But, Excel only fits 9 columns. In this document right and left margin set to 0.7 inches. It uses the Arial font and size 10.

**Expected :**

Portrait Orientation

System Resolution : 1360 x 768

Available Sheet Size after subtracting margin  = (8.27 - 1.4) x 96 = 659.52 pixels

First 10 columns with 64 pixels width = 64 x 10 = 640 pixels

640 pixels can be fit into 659.52 pixels PDF page.

**Result**

Only columns from 1 to 9 is fit into the first page of PDF.

What is logic or behavior of Excel for converting the document to PDF. What kind of scaling it uses?

[Download the Excel document here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fxdk4v16R1D6CFlro0DvuFQyPEPqFkeb/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

If you start from a
Excel template file you can already set the "print range" to your 9 columns.

If you then convert it to PDF it will show like you want it to.

To save as PDF you can use the following

```
ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF)
```